# How do I order static assets created from webpack-dev-server for temporary index.html?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have been following the Angular 2 documentation regarding webpack.  I am attempting to use the webpack-dev-server to help test my application.  The entry points include polyfills, vendor, and app.

When I attempt to run the dev server, the files get ordered as polyfills, app, and app.

Is there a way to explicitly order them when they get rendered in the index.html template?

```html
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
    cache: false,
    debug: true,

    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'vip-app': './src/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts'],
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: [ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css-loader'), 'to-string', 'css']
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Angular With Webpack</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="http://localhost:8080/vip-app.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>
    <vip-app-base-local-dev>Loading...</vip-app-base-local-dev>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/vip-app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/vendor.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `chunkSortMode` option from **HtmlWebpackPlugin** to achive it.

- https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin#configuration

> chunksSortMode: Allows to control how chunks should be sorted before
>   they are included to the html. Allowed values: 'none' | 'auto' |
>   'dependency' | {function} - default: 'auto'

For example

1) This option

```
chunksSortMode: 'none'
```

will sort your chunks in alphabetical order

2) The option

```
chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
```

will sort your chunks based on their dependencies with each other.

3) Also you can write custom function like:

```
function sortChunk(packages) {
  return function sort(a, b) {
     if (packages.indexOf(a.names[0]) > packages.indexOf(b.names[0])) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (packages.indexOf(a.names[0]) < packages.indexOf(b.names[0])) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
  }
}
```

And use it like

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   template: 'index.html',
   chunksSortMode: sortChunk(['vip-app', 'vendor', 'polyfills' ])
})
```

to achieve desired order

```
vip-app' => 'vendor' ==> 'polyfills'
```

Answer (score 0):

chunksSortMode only match entrypoint not chunks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).